# floating an element makes the animation smooth and reverse the direction?

Tags: css, animation, css-float, height

I am trying to create a simple animation where 3 bars go up and down at a certain time interval. I am making use of `height` and `animation-delay` to achieve the effect as you can see.

What's surprising is that when I float the bars, the direction of the animation seems to reverse. You can toggle the checkbox in demo to see that. I know floating an element takes it out of the document flow but can't understand how that might be changing the direction. Any explanations?

Also, when *not floated* the effect is jumpy. When I float the bars the animation is smooth. How can I get rid of the jumpy effect?

**What I tried?**

I thought it's `inline-block` issue that makes the adjacent bars shift a little because of a bar having less height during the animation. I tried to solve that problem by setting `font-size:0` to remove the **ghost space** among inline elements. No luck.

```js
/*DEMO PURPOSES*/
$("input").on("change", function() {
  $(".bar").toggleClass("pull-left");
})
```

```css
body {
  padding: 100px;
  font-size: 0;
}
.bar {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 20px;
  height: 40px;
  background: #000;
  display: inline-block;
  -webkit-animation: die 1s infinite ease-in-out;
  animation: die 1s infinite ease-in-out;
}
.delay-short {
  -webkit-animation-delay: .33s;
  animation-delay: .33s;
}
.delay-long {
  -webkit-animation-delay: .66s;
  animation-delay: .66s;
}
@-webkit-keyframes die {
  50% {
    height: 1px;
    opacity: .2;
  }
}
@keyframes die {
  50% {
    height: 1px;
    opacity: .2;
  }
}

/*DEMO PURPOSES*/

.pull-left {
  float: left;
}
label {
  font-size: 16px;
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<label for="floatToggle">Toggle Float
  <input type="checkbox" id="floatToggle" />
</label>

<div class="bar"></div>
<div class="bar delay-short"></div>
<div class="bar delay-long"></div>
```

**Update -** With the help of accepted answer I made this finally - http://codepen.io/praveenpuglia/details/dovygr/#stats

Comment: @humble.rumble 's answer fixed that issue. I am trying to understand the relation of float with animation

Comment: If you want do do it without changing the markup. then see the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/devjit/6g4d5ka4/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/float
>
> #### CSS/Properties/float
>
> - left
>     The element generates a block box that is floated to the left. Content flows on the right side of the box, **starting at the top**.
> - right
>     Similar to 'left', except the box is floated to the right, and content flows on the left side of the box, **starting at the top**.

Float pulls the element to the top of the containing block. You can use `position: absolute;` but they will overlap, so you need relatively positioned containing blocks to give them boundaries again. You can use `::before` to do this without adding markup.

```css
body {
    padding: 100px;
    font-size: 0;
}
.bar,
.bar::before {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 20px;
    height: 40px;
}
.bar::before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background: #000;
    -webkit-animation: die 1s infinite ease-in-out;
    animation: die 1s infinite ease-in-out;
}
.delay-short::before {
    -webkit-animation-delay: .33s;
    animation-delay: .33s;
}
.delay-long::before {
    -webkit-animation-delay: .66s;
    animation-delay: .66s;
}
@-webkit-keyframes die {
    50% {
        height: 1px;
        opacity: .2;
    }
}
@keyframes die {
    50% {
        height: 1px;
        opacity: .2;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="bar"></div>
<div class="bar delay-short"></div>
<div class="bar delay-long"></div>
```